# Weird problem with NSString initWithContentsOfFile

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, parsing, csv, nsstring

I have a .csv file in my bundle which I need to parse into an NSArray. The problem is when I init an NSString with contents of file (the file is located in my bundle), it returns nil. However, if I change the contents of the file, to anything else (random), it works. Is it possible there's some sort of string/character in the file that might be messing with the initialization?

It's just a simple csv file with 2 columns, a number, a comma, some text and "\n".

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

CSV => NSArray?

https://github.com/davedelong/CHCSVParser

*disclaimer: I wrote it.

---

Works for me:

```
NSStringEncoding usedEncoding = 0;
NSError *csvError = nil;
NSString *raw = [NSString stringWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=RXPPwpvy"] usedEncoding:&usedEncoding error:&csvError];
NSLog(@"raw: %@", raw);
NSLog(@"%@", [NSArray arrayWithContentsOfCSVString:raw encoding:usedEncoding error:&csvError]);
```

Comment: That's exactly what I tried before deciding to parse it myself. I always use this parser and it works perfectly, but this is the first it's not working. It just returns nil..
A bit off topic, but just read that you wrote this and I want to thank you for these classes as they have helped me out a lot.

Comment: @user635064 can you post the file? If the parser's not working, I'd like to know why.

Comment: Hi,here it is: http://pastebin.com/RXPPwpvy
Just copy paste from RAW Paste Data at the bottom. Thank you for your help.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply. I think I know what's going on. When I export it from excel into .csv format, it doesn't work. But, if I copy the contents of the file into textedit and then save it, then it works. Do you know what might be the problem? Thanks again.

Comment: @user635064 it's probably an encoding issue.  Try opening the file in something like TextWrangler to see what encoding it's saving the file as, and then use that encoding when reading the file.